Roles and User Management - Actions Dropdown not showing for default admin
I was working on a new project using abp.io and angular. Recently, the actions dropdown on Roles and Users management has dissapear both for the default admin role and user. I can see it if I create a new role or user. I have reviewed all my last changes, not related to Users or Roles. I have created a new project with the abp CLI and it has the same issue.
Please, any suggestion? I am really lost with this problem!!!!
Thank you
This is where it looks after
And this is now
I don't know what happen. Sorry but I can't provide more info.
